# PHP Accessing static properies via variable

Tags: php

Is there any way to access static property via variable that holds property name(Except of ReflectionClass and eval())?

```
class WhateverClass
{
    public static $test = array('1','2');
    public static $other = array('3','4');
}
$propName = 'test';
var_dump(WhateverClass::$propName);
```

Comment: I think you need to use double $ syntax for this.  Look up variable variables in PHP's manual.

Comment: did you try `WhateverClass::${$propName}` ?

Comment: I tried something like ` WhateverClass::{$propName}`. I totally forgot about $$. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work:

```
var_dump(WhateverClass::$$propName);
```

This is known as [variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

I'd try to minimise my use of that technique though, it could get very confusing very quickly if overused.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use "[variable variables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)".

```
$propName = 'test';
var_dump(WhateverClass::$$propName);
```

Note the two `$`.  That tells PHP to look for variable named... whatever `$propName` contains.